# How to read GenericRecord specific data in confluent kafka C#

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

This is my simple code snippet which try to to read the Avro generic record form consumer:

```
using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new SchemaRegistryConfig { SchemaRegistryUrl = schemaRegistryUrl }))
  using (var consumer = new 
        ConsumerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(new ConsumerConfig { BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers, GroupId = groupName })
                        .SetKeyDeserializer(new AsyncAvroDeserializer<string>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                        .SetValueDeserializer(new AsyncAvroDeserializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                        .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
                        .Build())
                {
      consumer.Subscribe(topicName);

      try
       {
           while (true)
             {
                try
                 {
                    var consumeResult = consumer.Consume();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {consumeResult.Message.Key}\nValue: {consumeResult.Value}");
                    Console.WriteLine(consumeResult.Value.Schema);
                            Console.WriteLine(consumeResult.Value.Schema["favorite_number"]);

                  }
                 catch (ConsumeException e)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine($"Consume error: {e.Error.Reason}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        // commit final offsets and leave the group.
                        consumer.Close();
                    }
                }
```

As you can see i have can log the schema but dont know how to get its data value.

```
 Console.WriteLine(consumeResult.Value.Schema);

 Console.WriteLine(consumeResult.Value.Schema["favorite_number"]);
```

While the schema and data is like this in this object `consumeResult.Value`:

{Schema: {"type":"record","name":"User","namespace":"Confluent.Kafka.Examples.AvroSpecific","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"favorite_number","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"favorite_color","type":["string","null"]}]}, **contents**: { name: sfs, favorite_number: 41, favorite_color: blue, }}

I want to read content data.

Comment: Is `consumeResult.Value` a string? Or is that a dynamicobject? `consumeResult.Value.contents["favorite_number"]` doesn't work? Otherwise it looks like it needs a JSON deserialization first.

Comment: value is TValue of GenericRecord, while consumeResult.Value.contents["favorite_number"], the content is not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the `content` is not accessible

I don't think `Value.contents` is what you want. Particularly because that property is `private`, as you mentioned

The getter is defined like a dictionary - [Source code](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/csharp/src/apache/main/Generic/GenericRecord.cs#L38-L41)

Try `consumeResult.Value["favorite_number"]`

---

When you do `consumeResult.Value.Schema["favorite_number"]`, you get the `Field` object within the schema not the value of the field within the outer record. - [Source code](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/csharp/src/apache/main/Schema/RecordSchema.cs#L159-L172)